# The number of even and odd natural numbers

Tags: infinity

Person A: *The number of even and odd natural numbers is equal, because they alternate each time.*
Person B: *There are far more even natural numbers. If you double an odd number, it's even. If you double an even number, it's still even.*

How do I best explain to a person with only base mathematical knowledge the truth of the matter?

Comment: I'd explain that *infinite*  is not a number, but a different, abstract, beast that *sometimes* can be be compared to a number, but most of times it has its own rules.

Comment: Only 1/3 of all numbers are even. Take the asymptotic limit: 1,3,2,5,7,4,9,11,6, 13,15,8, ...

Comment: Doubling introduces evenness and is therefore a failed attempt to classify this property.  One way to approach this is to take an increasing interval from the natural numbers and count the even and odd members.

Comment: Person C: There are far more odd numbers because every even number arises from adding 1 to an odd number. This "logic" as as false as that "doubles logic"

Comment: Thanks to all who contributed in comments or answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"There are more" is not well-defined for infinite sets. I think the real answer is that the question isn't meaningful. (The existence of an injective map is well-defined, but you can debate whether that means 'there are at most as many'.)

You may dispute the latter argument by pointing that "If you take a natural number and add its successor to it, the result is always odd". There are infinitely many functions $f : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ that always produce odd or always produce even numbers.

Comment: Would you have a suggestion how to best explain the issues of "infinity" to a person with mathemtaical knowledge of a ~9th grader?

Comment: Good question. I think what I would do is emphasize 'infinite' as a property rather than a thing. The natural numbers are defined as "0 is a NN, and for each NN, the successor is another NN". This defines a set, and all we can do is study properties of this set, which turn out to often be unintuitive. If the person says that 'there are more' should be a meaningful property, just ask them how they would define it. Dk if that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful for *me*. I did not convince the person I was speaking with - but it did end the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument only shows that in the "double naturals", there are far more even numbers than odd ones. The argument says nothing about the naturals themselves.

---

Modern theory says that there are as many even as odd naturals, because you can associate every even number to an odd one and conversely (add or subtract $1$).

But it also says that there are as many naturals as there are even ones (multiply and divide by $2$) ! And there are as many primes as there are naturals.

Comment: No, the theory does not say "as many", is says "have the same cardinality/there is bijection".

Comment: @Anixx: I expected this comment.